# Insurer's total expected amount of claims to be paid over 30 month period

Tags: probability, random-variables

Due to decreasing business, the amount an insurer expects to pay for claims will decrease at a constant rate of 5% per month indefinitely. This month the insurer paid 1000 in claims. What is the insurer's total expected amount of claims to be paid over the 30 month period that began this month?

I tried to come up with a proper equation but could n't. So I tried the tedious method of listing all the outcomes and summing it up to get the answer. The way i did this is:

> 1st month- 1000-1000*.05=950

I did the same thing till I got to 30th day of the month and then I summed all up to get approximately 12,992. However, the correct answer is 15,707. I asked my friend about it and he suggested using geometric series to solve it. So I did. I put all the information in the form of:

> 1000+1000*(.05)+1000*(.05)^2+...+1000*(.05)^29

If I sum it all up using summation formula of geometric series. I get the answer close to 1052. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that this is a geometric series, and you should use that to find your answer.

However, multiplying $1000$ by $0.05$ does not represent a decrease of $5\%$ - rather, it represents a decrease of $95\%$, which is why your final answer was much smaller than you would expect.

A decrease of $5\%$ implies multiplying by $1 - 0.05 = 0.95$, which is a much less dramatic change.

Your terms should be

$$1000, \,\,1000(0.95),\,\, 1000(0.95)^2,\,\, ...$$

This should give a more reasonable result :)